# How many instance context can be created for per call mechanism in WCF

Tags: c#, .net, excel, wcf

I'm in a process of implementing a WCF service, wherein the service will be hit by many requests at a time. After getting a request the WCF service would open an excel file to read data using Interop and send the request back to the server with the data that is read from the excel file. It takes 2-5 secs to open and read file in current system which does not uses WCF.  I want to use the per-call mechanism for instance creation in WCF. My question is that how many such requests will the Per-Call mechanism in WCF handle. If I have 100 requests at a time will the per-call mechanism able to sustain.Your suggestions/ideas will be very helpful.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After lot of googling I found the answer...

Throttling behavior: 
WCF throttling helps you to put an upper limit on the number of concurrent calls, WCF instances, and concurrent sessions. WCF provides three ways by which you can define upper limits: MaxConcurrentCalls, MaxConcurrentInstances, and MaxConcurrentSessions.

MaxConcurrentCalls: Limits the number of concurrent requests that can be processed by WCF service instances.
MaxConcurrentInstances: Limits the number of service instances that can be allocated at a given time. When it’s PerCall services, this value matches the number of concurrent calls. For PerSession services, this value equals the number of active session instances. This setting doesn’t matter for Single instancing mode, because only one instance is ever created.
MaxConcurrentSessions: Limits the number of active sessions allowed for the service

All the above three settings can be defined in the servicebehaviors tag as shown in the below XML snippet:

```
<serviceBehaviors> 

<behavior name="serviceBehavior"> 

<serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="16"
maxConcurrentInstances="2147483647" maxConcurrentSessions="10" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you host your WCF service on IIS then yes, IIS can handle more than 100 request per second and it's depend on your WCF service code to how to respond 100 request.

As you mention, your service read excel file and it take 2-5 second. If your execel file not frequent update then use caching to store/retrieve data. It would be helpful to increase your response time. User file based caching so when your excel update it's automatically get latest data.

Comment: Ya caching would come into the scene later. But would 100 or more instance created would harm the performance of the WCF service in case of per-call mechanism.

Comment: 100 or more instance is not a big issue because IIS is capable to handle number of request at a time. Many heavy traffic web site hosted on IIS but to improve performance or to mange load on server they use load balancing server.